# Fast find if points belong to polygon (NetTopologySuite.Geometries, C#. .net core 2.2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, nettopologysuite

Is there an efficient way to find points of type NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point that are inside given polygon of type NetTopologySuite.Geometries.PointPolygon
using .net core 2.2.
I tried following the documentation below, but no luck: https://nettopologysuite.github.io/html/class_net_topology_suite_1_1_algorithm_1_1_locate_1_1_indexed_point_in_area_locator.html#ad28b305b77c52327b7787ca8016c0fd7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one against many predicate tests use the `GeoAPI.Geometries.Prepared.IPreparedGeometry`.
You can create one using the `NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Prepared.PreparedGeometryFactory`.

```
private IList<IPoint> Contains(IGeometry geom, IEnumerable<IPoint> points) {
    var prepGeom = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Prepared.PreparedGeometryFactory().Prepare(geom);
    var res = new List<IPoint>();
    foreach(var point in points) {
        if (prepGeom.Contains(point)) res.Add(point);
    }
    return res;
}
```

[See issue on GitHub](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/issues/274#issuecomment-448283176)

Comment: There is also several options at the bottom of NetTopologySuite issue #264. https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/issues/264